# How do I make a service depend on another service on different server?

Tags: linux, service, dependencies

I have some java processes which need to be started by roster:

```
J1 on X --> J2 on Y --> J3 on Z
```

An idea comes to my mind is let J1 start automatically and use Nagios + NRPE to start J2 based the J1 state. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ssh` with public key encryption.

I had an environment like this.  Starting the primary (`J1` in your example) would connect to host `Y` and run command `J2`. Again, in your example, I would make the startup of `J2` do the same thing: connect to `Z` and start `J3`.

Use `ssh` this way (with a public key) to start J2 from X:

```
ssh -i J2-on-Y.key user@y start j2
```

Likewise, starting up J2 on Y would have this command:

```
ssh -i J3-on-Z.key user@z start j3
```

With this in place, starting J1 would bring up all of the rest.  Don't forget to account for shutdown as well - as well as the case when a startup is attempted but the process is already running.